# What is the correct way of expressing the general solution of $\sin x=0,1,-1$ and $\cos x=0,-1,1$?

Tags: trigonometry

The general solution of $\sin x = \sin y$ is $x = n\pi + (-1)^ny$. Then if $\sin x = 1$ or $\sin x = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$ or $x = n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}$. Is this correct?

Also, the general solution of $\cos x = \cos y$ is $x = 2n\pi \pm y$. Then if $\cos x = 0$ or $x = 2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. Is this correct?

Also for $\cos x = 1,-1$, I am confused.

Comment: you can use math mode in comments too, by adding \$ around your math expressions. For example \$  \cos ( \sqrt {\int _a ^b f(x) dx)} \$ = $ \cos ( \sqrt {\int _a ^b f(x) dx)} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearest way of writing the solutions are
$$
\sin{x} = \sin{y} \Leftrightarrow x = y + n2\pi \text{  or  } x = \pi - y + n2\pi$
$$
$$
\cos{x} = \cos{y} \Leftrightarrow x = \pm y + n2\pi
$$
where $n$ is a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1,$

If $f(n)=n\pi+(-1)^n\dfrac\pi2, f(1)=f(0)$

Again $2m\pi\pm\dfrac\pi2$ is same  as $(2r+1)\dfrac\pi2$  where $r,m$ are  integers

Finally for $\cos x=1=\cos0\implies x=2k\pi\pm0$ where $k$ is any integer

Comment: It's not that clear.

Comment: @user451361, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: i think that if x=n(pi)+(-1)^n*y then in case of sinx=1, x=n(pi)+(-1)^n*(pi)/2 must also be correct, i am not convinced here

Comment: @user451361, Observe that  $$1\cdot\pi+(-1)^1\dfrac\pi2=0\cdot\pi+(-1)^0\dfrac\pi2$$

Comment: can you derive 2mπ±π2 is same as (2r+1)π2 where r,m are integers?

Comment: @user451361, Just put a few values of $m$  say $0,\pm1,\pm2$ and those of $r$